# Issue displaying data in angular model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I have created a dropdown using ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
            <div ng-show="editConfig" class="input-group" theme="bootstrap" style="">
                <label class="config-row-element ">Product Type</label>
      <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control config-dropdown"  style="" ng-model="event.etype" id="etype">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Product</option>
          <option ng-repeat="etype in etypes" ng-value="etype[0]">{{etype[1]}}</option>
      </select>
        </div>
```

In the controller, all of the etypes are contained in an array where each etype contains two items: one is the name the selection must be stored in on the backend and one is the display name. It looks like this:

`$scope.etypes = [['gif','GIF Booth'], ['photo','Photo Booth'], ['ipad', 'iPad'], ['video','Video Booth'], ['print','#Print']];`

From the user perspective, when they are selecting an option, they choose from Gif Booth, Photo Booth, etc... however, the 'gif', 'photo', etc. gets bound to the ng-model `event.etype`. So now when I try and display the selection when they are no longer editing, the uglier version appears.

```
        <tr ng-hide="editConfig">
          <th>Product Type</th>
          <td style="overflow: hidden">{{event.etype}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Is there a way to solve this easily just within HTML? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GeraldChablowski I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Can you elucidate a bit? I'm sorry. I'm new to Angular and not sure what is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your model and your value to take the entire array string then convert it to an array on change.

```
           <div class="input-group" theme="bootstrap" style="">
            <label class="config-row-element ">Product Type</label>
  <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control config-dropdown"  ng-model="etype" ng-change="showEvent(etype)">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Product</option>
      <option ng-repeat="etype in etypes" ng-value="etype">{{etype[1]}}</option>
  </select>
    </div>
```

You selected: {{selected}}

And in your js:

```
 $scope.showEvent = function(e){
  var array = e.split(',')
  $scope.selected = array[1];
}
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cSuLAvUY5PYUUr7YvNWF?p=preview).  I believe this is what you are looking for.  If it is not, just let me know.  Maybe I am not understanding your issue correctly.

Comment: Thanks! So the issue still is that I need the ng-value to be equal to 'gif' or 'ipad', etc. That is what has to be sent to the backend without needing to be filtered.

In this case, the set of 'gif' and 'Gif Booth'  are still being sent to the model.

Comment: But this actually helps, because I can use the javascript code you gave me to assign the ng-model as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, create a new scope variable that uses object dot notation instead of the nested arrays:

```
$scope.etypes = [['gif','GIF Booth'], ['photo','Photo Booth'], ['ipad', 'iPad'], ['video','Video Booth'], ['print','#Print']];
$scope.all_etypes = [];
for (var i=0; i < $scope.etypes.length; i++) {
    $scope.all_etypes.push({ id: $scope.etypes[i][0], name: $scope.etypes[i][1] });
}
```

This code will create a new scope variable called `all_etypes` that looks like this:

```
[
  { id: 'gif', name: 'GIF Booth' },
  { id: 'photo', name: 'Photo Booth' },
  { id: 'ipad', name: 'iPad' },
  { id: 'video', name: 'Video Booth' },
  { id: 'print', name: '#Print' },
]
```

This is much easier to work with.

Now, update your HTML to use this new scope variable:

```
<div ng-show="editConfig" class="input-group" theme="bootstrap" style="">
    <label class="config-row-element">Product Type</label>
    <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control config-dropdown" style="" ng-model="event.etype" id="etype">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Product</option>
        <option ng-repeat="etype in all_etypes" ng-value="etype.id">{{etype.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<tr ng-hide="editConfig">
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <td style="overflow: hidden">{{event.etype.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Oh, I see a problem.  You're specifying that index 0 is the ng-value which is what will be displayed to the user.  You should either change the ng-value to `etype` only or do as Gerald Chablowski suggested in the comment on your post and use a second variable to track things easier.  Otherwise, you're going to have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately when you do that, there are two issues.
1. It gets sent to the server incorrectly 
2. For some reason, this gets interpreted as a string and not an array, and calling the index 1 actually displays a single letter. If the user selects ipad, for example, event.etype[1] will display as the letter ```p```. If I console.log(event.etype[1]), it gets shown correctly, however. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it will be best if you work with object like:

```
$scope.etypes = [{'id':'gif','name':'GIF Booth'}, {'id':photo','name':'Photo Booth'}, {'id':ipad', 'name':'iPad'}, {'id':video','name':'Video Booth'}, {'id':'print','name':'#Print'}];
```

view :

```
<div ng-show="editConfig" class="input-group" theme="bootstrap" style="">
   <label class="config-row-element ">Product Type</label>
      <select class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu form-control config-dropdown"  style="" ng-model="event.etype" id="etype">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Select a Product</option>
          <option ng-repeat="etype in etypes" ng-value="etype">{{etype.name}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

2nd view :

```
<tr ng-hide="editConfig">
  <th>Product Type</th>
  <td style="overflow: hidden">{{event.etype.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

To send it, you will have to filter the object.

Comment: Hi Gerald. Thanks for taking the time to respond to this. I tried what you suggested, but the issue is that the ng-value is set to just ```etype.id``` which means I can't call ```{{event.etype.name}}``` as that doesn't exist. The only thing that is being sent on submission is just the ```etype.id```.

Comment: It's edited. I just change ng-value to make it link to the object.